# Routing based on host

Tags: next.js

iam migrating app to next.js and i am struggling with configuring domains, locales and routes.
I've started with custom express server, which define routes based on request domain. But I've ended up with recognizing that custom server and detecting locale is not supported.

What I exactly need:

- given routes test.com, test.fr, test.cz
- that I need set routes valid for current domain.. For example test.cz/kosik and test.com/basket should show basket. So test.com/kosik or test.cz/basket will throw an 404.
- I need compute locale from host (test.cz -> cs, test.com -> en). I didn't find any aproach how to do that with custom express server.

Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: For the domain routing, have you had a look at Next.js built-in [i18n routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#domain-routing)?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure next.js to assign domains to different locales like this:

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en-US', 'cs-CZ'],
    defaultLocale: 'en-US',
    domains: [
      {
        domain: 'test.com',
        defaultLocale: 'en-US',
      },
      {
        domain: 'test.cz',
        defaultLocale: 'cs-CZ',
      }
    ],
  },
}
```